# Directory error when trying to call from another java program

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a java program from another java program in a different directory. I get a "no such file or directory" error but I can copy and paste the directory I'm trying to reach from the error and it works fine.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -classpath /home/paleus/directories/trunk/web/postProc PostProcAuto": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:474)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:610)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:483)
    at PreParseAuto.parseEmail(PreParseAuto.java:352)
    at PreParseAuto.main(PreParseAuto.java:79)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:467)
    ... 4 more
[paleus@vm20031 preParsing]$ java -classpath /home/paleus/directories/trunk/web/postProc PostProcAuto
Please run as: inFile outFile procType[Inferencing=0|Phone=1|Email=2|Addr=3]
[paleus@vm20031 preParsing]$
```

Comment: Maybe the java command isn't in your path

Comment: Process x = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java -classpath " + postProcPath +" PostProcAuto", outFile.split("\\."), "2"});

Comment: You can see whats the current directory from where you get the error and make sure its same as  the preParsing directory from which this code works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the command a full path

So instead of

```
java --classpath ...
```

do

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7\bin\java --classpath ...
```

Also, you might need to quote the arguments if they have spaces

Comment: This is on a linux VM so I don't know the full path to the java binary.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

Needed to be:

```
Process x = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-classpath",postProcPath,"PostProcAuto",outFile.split("\\."), "2"});
```

Rather than:

```
Process x = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java -classpath " + postProcPath +" PostProcAuto", outFile.split("\\."), "2"});
```